# Google Drive Quickstart -This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found

Tags: android, eclipse, api, google-api, javadoc

In MainActivity.java, it says **This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found**, for all the imports below, which are from Drive API. It will not debug because they have no referenced sources and javadocs.

```
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
```

How do I attach javadocs and sources for them? Can they even be modified under Java build path... wouldn't let me edit anything.....

Answer (score 0):

Go to project->properties->Java build path->order and export and move the Drive API to the top.

No need to check o uncheck it.

Answer (score 0):

In the build path you need to include the external API of your jar file.